# How to avoid variable capturing in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

Lately I've read C# in Depth and it taught me about lambda expression, I've been using them to pas data to click events and such like:

```
image.MouseDown+=(o ,e)=>MethodToDoSomething(DataNeededForAction);
```

now the problem with those is variable capturing when used in a foreach loop (thank you Jon Skeet for making that part really clear :), when initializing several objects that have events that I subscribe to I usually bump into an issue with variable capturing. consider the following example:

```
foreach (var game in GamesCollection)
{
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Width = 100;
    img.MouseDown+=(o,e) => MyMethod(game.id);
}
```

To avoid capturing in this situation I have to add some variable to assign game to and then pass that variable to the method, this creates extra unclear code and mostly, additional clutter.
Is there a way to bypass this? Something that'll at least look cleaner?

Thx, Ziv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(EDIT: Note that this has changed with C# 5, where `foreach` now effectively creates a fresh variable for each iteration.)

No, there's no way of avoiding this. Basically it was a mistake in the way the language specification described `foreach` in terms of a single variable, rather than a new variable per iteration. Personally I don't see it as a problem in terms of the amount of code involved - by the time you've realised that it's a problem and figured out how to fix it, you've got over the biggest hurdle. I'd normally include a comment to make it obvious to maintenance programmers, mind you.

I'm sure the C# team would do it differently if they were starting from scratch, but they're not. Heck, [they've even discussed changing the existing behaviour](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)... but there are good reasons *against* that change (notably that code which works correctly on a C# N+1 compiler would still compile, but give the wrong result on a C# N compiler; a very subtle source of bugs for open source library authors who expect their code to be built with multiple compilers).

(Hope you're enjoying the book, btw...)

Comment: Since this answer was written, the C# team has decided to make the breaking change of moving the loop variable logically inside the loop in C# 5 (the linked article is updated). The code in the question now works without having to copy the `game` variable.

Comment: @AndersAbel: Indeed. Unfortunately there are far too many answers to go back and fix them all now :(

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. You need to create extra storage to keep the correct instance of `game` available in the method closure.

Comment: I understand this is a limitation of the compiler, but I wonder if it would be possible to improve the compiler to detect it and automate it. Is there any technical reason that this wouldn't be possible?

Comment: It's simply not how it works. foreach only uses a single variable declaration for storing the Enumerator.Current which gets overwritten on each pass. This is what gets captured in the method closure. I don't see that it needs changing.

Comment: I know that's not how it works, but I'm asking why make the decision to do it that way. A compiler could potentially detect that the iteration variable is captured and account for it by adding the temporary assignment automatically. Almost every problem I see with people using closures is due to capturing the iteration variable. I'm asking if there's any technical/logical reason as to why a future language/compiler could not automate it, as I can't think of any practical reason where anybody would want to capture the iteration variable.

Comment: I think that making a special case would prove more confusing than beneficial and effectively require an understanding of two different modes of operation.

Answer (score 0):

If `GamesCollection` is a `List<T>`, you can use the `ForEach` method:

```
GamesCollection.ForEach(game => {
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Width = 100;
    img.MouseDown+=(o,e) => MyMethod(game.id);
});
```

But in general, no. And one extra variable is not really that cluttered.

Comment: Sure, but effectively this creates a new reference to each Game in GamesCollection in the parameter of the delegate that you supply to ForEach, so it's really much the same thing.

Comment: @spender right. As I read the question, he was trying to avoid extra lines of code, not necessarily extra references.

Answer (score -1):

What about pulling out the game.id first with a LINQ expression.  Pushing the call through .Aggregate() should make a new variable each time because it is really a method parameter.

```
GamesCollection.Select(game => game.id).Aggregate((_, id) => {
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Width = 100;
    img.MouseDown+=(o,e) => MyMethod(id);
    return img;
});
```